# Can nouns license their complements to be followed?

Tags: nouns, complements

> The spying row between Australia and Indonesia shows no sign of easing, and overnight a powerful minister within the Indonesian government said talks about any future cooperation on asylum seekers have also been suspended, throwing the Abbott Government's ***turn-back*** the boats policy into disarray. ([ABC.net.au](http://www.abc.net.au/am/content/2013/s3895683.htm))

It seems like *turn-back* is a noun. But what I’m wondering is whether nouns can license complements, in this case ‘the boats’, to be followed like intransitive verbs?

Comment: Nouns can license a few kinds of complements: preposition phrases (*loss **of blood***, *an attack **by Godzilla***), finite subordinate clauses (*suspicion **that he wasn't really a butler***), and non-finite subordinate clauses (*the ability **to drink milk through one's nose***).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a mistake. *Turn-back* as a single word doesn't mean anything that I'm aware of. I think what was intended was for "turn back the boats" to be a compound adjective describing *policy*. It should have been written as:

> ...throwing the Abbot Government's turn-back-the-boats policy into disarray.

That many hyphens can be a bit unwieldy, however, and although the above is correct I probably would have written it this way instead:

> ...throwing the Abbot Government's "turn back the boats" policy into disarray.

Either way, "turn back the boats" is a descriptor of *policy*.